# How to get Paired BLE device in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I connect BLE with CoreBluetooth and paired.

Now when I back to my app screen, I want to make sure that BLE already paired with iOS device.

1. If I store value in defaults and remove app, this case will not work to fetch device.
2. If user remove paired bluetooth peripheral from Setting -> Bluetooth -> list of devices this case also not work to identify.

   ```
   NSArray *ary = [self.bleMgr retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]]];

   NSUUID *nsUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:identifier];
   NSArray *temp = [self.bleMgr retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[nsUUID]];
   ```

Above both code lines not giving robust result.

How to get that paired BLE device in app?

Comment: are you getting the same uuid every time?

Comment: @HSAM yes getting same uuid for each ble.

Answer (score 3):

The first time you discover a peripheral, the system generates an identifier (a UUID, represented by an NSUUID object) to identify the peripheral.

You can then store this identifier (using, for instance, the resources of the NSUserDefaults class), and later use it to try to reconnect to the peripheral using the retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: method of the CBCentralManager class.

The following describes one way to use this method to reconnect to a peripheral you’ve previously connected to.

```
knownPeripherals = [myCentralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:savedIdentifiers];
```

> The NSUUID class is not toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation’s
>   CFUUID. Use UUID strings to convert between CFUUIDRef and NSUUID, if
>   needed. Two NSUUID objects are not guaranteed to be comparable by
>   pointer value (as CFUUID is); use isEqual(_:) to compare two NSUUID
>   instances.

Refer this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid

Refer last two sections: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW1

Comment: what happen in this case !!

1. If I store value in defaults and remove app, this case will not work to fetch device.

Comment: yes correct, then the only way left is to store uuid in keychain

Comment: OK, second case, 

If user remove paired bluetooth peripheral from Setting -> Bluetooth -> list of devices this case also not work to identify.

Comment: So now here you have handle the case using do try catch block, in catch you will get the error that it's not able to connect, so you have to connect manually again

Comment: Sorry, i could not get your try catch logic. Where you want to put ? 
****
in connect peripheral or else.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518768-peripheral

Comment: Brother please help. really i am getting any value by setNotify characteristic. How to know that which characterisitc used for notify ?

Comment: My BLE cannot connect again (connect and disconnect immediately), if i remove paired from device setting. So is it issue from hardware side or iOS side ?

Comment: I am not sure but when you do iOS settings changes, it will relaunch the app with new behaviour, so you cannot expect the app to connect it by itself, first put some condition to check the settings and then do try connecting it.

Comment: I would strongly refer you to read the Entire Core Bluetooth documentation

Comment: Do you have any tutorial for strong pairing and forget case ? or any helpful links. Please

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

Comment: https://medium.com/@kbabcockuf/bridging-the-gap-bluetooth-le-security-aab27232a767